# Is it still true that external include-guards lead to faster compiling times in large C++ projects?

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, include-guards

Let me start by defining what is usually called "external include-guards". Suppose you have a header file called `someheader.h` and a code file called `source.cpp`. You can have the traditional include-guards inside `someheader.h`:

```
//someheader.h
#ifndef _SOMEHEADER_H_
#define _SOMEHEADER_H_
// ...
#endif  // _SOMEHEADER_H_
```

In the past, I have heard and read multiple times that in really large projects, it would be better for the compiling performance to also have external include guards. which means:

```
//source.cpp
#ifndef _SOMEHEADER_H_
#include "someheader.h"
#endif
// ...
```

I guess the reason for such an advice is that with the checking for whether `someheader.h` had already been processed happening inside `source.cpp`, the compiler could entirely avoid having to search for `someheader.h`, open it and just then do the checking. That would be particularly useful in big projects with many levels of nested header inclusions.

Is such an optimization for compiling-times still relevant nowadays, with compilers gcc and visual studio being a lot more well developed?

Comment: I don't know if there is a definitive answer to this question. I would be surprised if someone could come up with hard numbers. I would expect that these "external include-guards" don't make a significant difference compared to the time it takes to actually compile source code, specially if you account for the time spent on optimization.

Comment: In large projects one uses precompiled header.

Comment: You'd save a very small amount of time, but you'd have to build a _lot_ to make up for the time the developer spends adding those external include guards.  (And if your compiler supports `#pragma once` the time saved would be minimal.